# C# how to protect set accessor to avoid the property be set from another class?

Tags: c#, object

The title can be confusing but I didn't find other words. It is better to explain what I want using a sample.
Imagine I have 2 classes. One of them have the other class as property:

```
public class Order {
   public int?Id { get; protected set; }
   public Client Client { get; set; }

   public void Save() {
      RequestBLL bll = new RequestBLL();
      bll.Save(this);
   }

   public static Order GetBy_Id(int id) {
      RequestBLL bll = new RequestBLL();
      return bll.Get<Order>(id);
   }
}

public class Client {
   public int?Id { get; protected set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public void Save() {
      RequestBLL bll = new RequestBLL();
      bll.Save(this);
   }

   public static Client GetBy_Id(int id) {
      RequestBLL bll = new RequestBLL();
      return bll.Get<Client>(id);
   }
}
```

Supposing the classes are in a different assembly than the application and the application has a reference to the assembly where the classes are. The application accesses the database and creates a Client object. The same application accesses the database and creates an Order object. This Order object has the Client property with the same data as the previously Client object created. Both Client objects have the same data, in fact should be the same object, but they are different objects. The application  updates the Client.Name property using the Client object and Save the object to the database. It is not reflected in the Client inside Order object. If the Order object is saved to the database the previous update will be lost since Order object contains a Client object with the old data:

```
Client c = Client.GetBy_Id(1);
Order o = Order.GetBy_Id(5);  //It has Client.Id = 1
c.Name = "Some Name";
c.Save();
o.Client.Name = "Another Name";
o.Save();
```

I would like a way to avoid the second update of the Client Name (through Order object) and only permits the first update directly using the Client object.
I checked all the modifiers and didn't find anyone that could be used. I tried:

```
public Client Client { get; internal set; }
```

But it only avoid to set the Client property to a Client object. The Name still can be set:

```
c.Name = "Some Name"; //Works! It is fine.
o.Client = c; //Fails! The Client accessor does not permit this set. It is fine!
o.Client.Name = "Another Name"; //Works! And it is just what I don't want.
```

I know someone could advise to don't do this in the application, but it is not so simple. It is only a simple sample I used to illustrate the situation. The issue is happening inside the framework in a circular reference of several objects. The application is only saving the Order object with the Client Name updated. It is not in fact saving the other Client object. The issue in the framework is due to the circular reference. So I am trying to resolve avoiding the application to create this situation, forcing the Client.Name be updated only using a direct Client object and not through a Client object inside another object.
Is there any way to implement this? I am using my own created Entity Framework. I wonder if this same issue happens on professional frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best way how to deal with it is to use interface(s). You let `Client` class to implement `IClient` interface and change `Client` property return type to `IClient`.

As `IClient` interface exposes only getter you cannot set `Name` property on in, unless you convert/cast value to `Client` type.

```
public class Order {
   public int? Id { get; protected set; }
   public IClient Client { get; set; }

   public void Save() {
      RequestBLL bll = new RequestBLL();
      bll.Save(this);
   }

   public static Order GetBy_Id(int id) {
      RequestBLL bll = new RequestBLL();
      return bll.Get<Order>(id);
   }
}

public interface IClient {
   public int? Id { get; }
   public string Name { get; }

   public void Save();
}

public class Client : IClient {
   public int? Id { get; protected set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public void Save() {
      RequestBLL bll = new RequestBLL();
      bll.Save(this);
   }

   public static Client GetBy_Id(int id) {
      RequestBLL bll = new RequestBLL();
      return bll.Get<Client>(id);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps
Petr

Comment: Thank you Petr. It helped a lot. I implemented your suggestion and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @MarceloTropia: I am happy to hear that! I wish you all the best with your project.